# How can I access different services on raspberry pi with a domain name instead of the ip:port way?

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, webserver

I have Homebridge and Pi-Hole running on my raspberry pi 3B+. Now what I want is the both services to be accessable via a dns name instead of the ip and port in the url.

homebridge: 192.168.0.88:8581 ==> homebridge.merckarion.home

pihole: 192.168.0.88 ==> pihole.merckarion.home

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this relatively easily. First, [configure pi-hole's local DNS to point the domain names you want to the pi's IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKgfD.png). Then, edit `/etc/lighttpd/external.conf` to reverse-proxy the Homebridge domain to the correct port:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_proxy" )

$HTTP["host"] == "home.bridge" {
        proxy.server = ( "/" => ( (
                "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                "port" => 8581
        ) ) )
}
```

Finally, restart the lighttpd service with `sudo systemctl restart lighttpd`. Obviously you'll want to replace `home.bridge` with your desired domain name.

I'm using one of the default domain names for the pi-hole admin. If you want to use a non-default name, you'll need to add the following to `external.conf` as otherwise lighttpd won't know how to serve your request:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "mycoolpiholedomain.biz" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/html/admin/"
}
```